# How do I align check boxes horizontal to one an other

Tags: html, css

Quick question, I was wondering if it is possible to align my 3 checkbox's and there paragraphs horizontally to one an other instead of the way there are now which is vertical

thanks for any help

```html
 <div class="wrapper3">
 <p>Do You Want Sound ?</p>
 <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="sound">Yes
    <p>Do You want Flashes ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="flash">Yes
    <p>Do You want Text ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="text">Yes
    <br />
 </div>
```

Comment: use `span` not `p`, since these aren't paragraphs at all. then `br` for new lines between them.

Comment: You should be using a `label` instead of a `p` tag...and break tags  should not be used for spacing. That's what margins / padding are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d prefer using proper semantic Markup without inline CSS:

```
<div class="wrapper3">
  <p>
    <strong>Do You Want Sound?</strong>
    <label for="sound">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="sound"> Yes
    </label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Do You want Flashes?</strong>
    <label for="flash">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="flash">Yes
    </label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Do You want Text?</strong>
    <label for="text">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="text">Yes
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

And here’s the accompanying CSS:

```
.wrapper3 p {
  display : inline-block;
  margin : 0;
  padding : 1em;
  border : none;
}

.wrapper3 label {
  display : block;
}

.wrapper3 input {
  color: #000;
}
```

By the way, you labeled the checkboxes with "Yes", but their values said "No". I’ve changed that in my code sample. Here’s a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ds5zcUYZvfbNZXKMBgZU?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that by wrapping your paragraph and the checkbox inside a `<div>` along with changing the `display` property of your `<p>` tag to `inline-block`. Here's a demo:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper3">
  <div>
    <p>Do You Want Sound ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="sound">Yes</div>
  <div>
    <p>Do You want Flashes ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="flash">Yes</div>
  <div>
    <p>Do You want Text ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="text">Yes</div>
  <br />
</div>
```